# c# form hangs when new thread starts

Tags: c#, multithreading

I created new thread and start it !
When new thread is running, Winform is hanging(freezing)
Why winform hangs ?
I want WinForm to move freely when I start a new thread
how to do it ?
(I will not use thread pool here.)

```
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate ()
            {
                Run();
            }));
            t1.Start();
            t1.Join();
            MessageBox.Show("Complete");
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            int a = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 999999999; i++)
            {
                ++a;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you know what a Join does? You start the thread, and then you Join. Join means that the current thread will wait and block until that thread is complete.

Comment: Never call Thread.Join() on the UI thread.  Putting the Show() call in an event handler for the RunWorkerCompleted event provided by BackgroundWorker would be a very simple way to get this right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read the documentation about Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Blocks the calling thread until the thread represented by this
>   instance terminates.

So, you start the thread, and then you Join, which means, that your UI thread will block and wait for the thread to finish.

You could do [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async):

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(Run);
    MessageBox.Show("Complete");
}
```

Comment: Just a tip. The only valid reason to use async void methods is in the case where you need an asynchronous event handler.

Comment: Isn't that kind of obvious? If you mark a method with the `async` modifier and you never await anything, the intellisense even tells you to remove it.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't get your point. The point was about the method being void, not Task. I agree with you. Another valid reason is when you are overriding parent non-async methods. ;)

Comment: Not to advertise :P but I have done a video detailing Threads it might help you understand them better https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXg9g56FS0k